# How to export .docx style_map to mammoth python and embed?

Tags: python, ms-word, mammoth

I have a .docx document that I am trying to convert to html.  It has some custom styles.  Can the styles be exported to `mammoth` or embedded with the word document directly (word ui)?

I did see some [comments](https://github.com/mwilliamson/python-mammoth/issues/90#issue-636114846) about using `python-docx` to export style to `mammoth` but they were light on details.

Below is the code I used to access the styles in the document using `docx`

```
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE

document = Document("some.docx")

styles = document.styles

# Do you choose a style from styles and embed? 
mammoth.embed_style_map(docx_file, styles[0] )
```

Is there a way to export those styles to `mammoth`?
Thank you in advance